# transform video files to pixels from external source in R

Tags: r, dataframe, image-processing

I want to create the predicative model in line with the image processing, I have a lot of video files(.mov) on my Google Drive (concerned with auto driving) I get data from Google Drive as links to the files. My disk and data are available for all Internet users.

## test

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1JidqB3TfHn0Cky8VBXHjbmHu7s0rGLrO?usp=sharing

## train

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1WIFQIC23_o1__BPmlRDpnYYwmthH2AP-?usp=sharing

```
library("googledrive") 

X=googledrive::drive_ls(path ="test")
Label=googledrive::drive_ls(path ="train")
```

So example structure of dataframe from google disk (If necessary)

dput()

```
train=structure(list(name = structure(c(1L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 
5L, 4L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("<chr>", "047a188c-1ac1965c.mov", 
"047a7ecb-68221e4a.mov", "047c278b-452d36f8.mov", "047e715f-3e47a9aa.mov", 
"047e715f-81e81a28.mov", "047e732b-aa79a87d.mov", "0571873b-de675e01.mov", 
"0571873b-faf718b2.mov", "0573e933-a8b4cf7d.mov", "0573f031-8ef23cf6.mov"
), class = "factor"), id = structure(c(1L, 5L, 7L, 11L, 9L, 3L, 
10L, 8L, 4L, 2L, 6L), .Label = c("<chr>", "115rWp3h3Of3Rx61mqDRfhatFMFOpImRf", 
"1EfokXp8UAxYKlpmGAIwU3FRJTTqrgDrS", "1EJa-A0a4_4nVgeF-pBXh6q6DFToGTYFu", 
"1HHML9bo4UPY9r1hIL9igSX_t5FXH5n82", "1HzVTOqRwNfxVDey6EYmDe2nd8hnnTbHT", 
"1IhMQiiCyb_WcKif8qyQmeK1W0tb8iU-U", "1lQc1a0mFw158T9U_QRvgoF0a33xiehZc", 
"1StqEC_7hJO4HJ9uvC0o7sjLLY3tdceNp", "1thEsWrcYFN4qgG57RCUxqCr7WE6ecrmq", 
"1xcxAuHamoFKHCD05wHfdVjeVDEN-FW8C"), class = "factor"), drive_resource = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("<list [41]>", 
"<list>"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("name", "id", "drive_resource"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))



test=structure(list(name = structure(c(1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 
8L, 7L, 6L, 5L), .Label = c("<chr>", "ddbd3eb2-ed0fde54.mov", 
"ddbf7bbb-c1908e76.mov", "ddd140cc-c54a4e82.mov", "df94066c-654dcae9.mov", 
"df94066c-b5e96c4c.mov", "df952550-4cb35087.mov", "df9b2e94-c14fc6a7.mov", 
"df9b8801-a11fba46.mov", "df9cc07f-5cec2c16.mov", "dfa06e5c-aa220d9a.mov"
), class = "factor"), id = structure(c(1L, 10L, 2L, 3L, 8L, 6L, 
11L, 7L, 9L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("<chr>", "18fDVBhfyAHqUffG0GNFGti7549G43bhZ", 
"1aYVn6L7147dDPcOb5CKC3RHh28fS7qix", "1Evm3EotD1xRoljlVCZ3sDIMnEmKaTbO5", 
"1jhbfo3NSKKjbLrMkEh-HRx-UIOUr6R5o", "1kK5AvfwTV_exoWO55dEwEH4QIHaqpVER", 
"1mjr8xSRdULPbmkQN-7L5Dx9yMb_zLxWh", "1OSg6d4q9is80c9Oark6ktdXwvZI8IpER", 
"1Q3UlVeZXDF2cjglqxToapX2FMgRABhA9", "1uIS-Y3N_ipDuzG8kVT5gP3VScAvS-B9_", 
"1yXKCCfgMJVbLqEyTJJCjS_pKQLMnZ6Kp"), class = "factor"), drive_resource = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("<list [41]>", 
"<list>"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("name", "id", "drive_resource"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```

To perform analysis i must convert video and(or) images into pixels, in my case it is video,so i do so.

```
require(EBImage)
# Dataframe of resized images
rs_df <- data.frame()

# Main loop: for each image, resize and set it to greyscale
for(i in 1:nrow(X))
{
  # Try-catch
  result <- tryCatch({
    # Image (as 1d vector)
    img <- as.numeric(X[i,])
    # Reshape as a 64x64 image (EBImage object)
    img <- Image(img, dim=c(64, 64), colormode = "Grayscale")
    # Resize image to 28x28 pixels
    img_resized <- resize(img, w = 28, h = 28)
    # Get image matrix (there should be another function to do this faster and more neatly!)
    img_matrix <- img_resized@.Data
    # Coerce to a vector
    img_vector <- as.vector(t(img_matrix))
    # Add label
    label <- labels[i,]
    vec <- c(label, img_vector)
    # Stack in rs_df using rbind
    rs_df <- rbind(rs_df, vec)
    # Print status
    print(paste("Done",i,sep = " "))},
    # Error function (just prints the error). Btw you should get no errors!
    error = function(e){print(e)})
}
```

after i get the list with errors like

next

```
names(rs_df) <- c("label", paste("pixel", c(1:776))) #776 video .mov files
```

I think video weren't loaded in R. I dont know why. i need help.

As output i want like this

```
   label pixel.1 pixel.2 pixel.3 pixel.4 pixel.5 pixel.6 pixel.7
1    304     304     304     304     304     304     304     304
2     32      32      32      32      32      32      32      32
3    350     351     351     351     351     351     351     351
4    265     265     265     265     265     265     265     265
5    108     108     108     108     108     108     108     108
6     87      87      87      87      87      87      87      87
7    191     192     192     192     192     192     192     192
8    170     170     170     170     170     170     170     170
9    329     329     329     329     329     329     329     329
10   268     268     268     268     268     268     268     268
11   238     238     238     238     238     238     238     238
12   159     159     159     159     159     159     159     159
13   220     221     221     221     221     221     221     221
```

How to convert videodatat to pixel dataframr.
Tnank you.

Answer (score 0):

I get answer here
https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/issues/14061
Package imager.